# How to Create Visual Studio 2013 Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I am interested to create a visual studio 2013 extension. I have gone through some of the msdn links. I am looking for adding one extra option when you right click on any .cs file/folder/project/solution, then on clicking that option some processing will be done on the .cs file/s. And lastly when the processing is done, the output should get print on a result window.

Edit -> Or May be Right Click -> Processing on .cs files -> open a windows form.

Similar to what happens when we do - Search/Replace in all files.

I know there are some options like - VSIX Project template, Editor templates, Visual Studio Package and Visual Studio Shell Isolated.

But i am not getting which one will help me out.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks,
jash

Comment: I got the answer - we have to create a new VS package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer - we have to create a new VS package